# How to create running totals in CouchDB (like SQL window functions)

Tags: javascript, couchdb

Edited the question for clarity:

Assume I have the following documents in CouchDB:

```json
{
  "_id": "1",
  "date": 1672119898,
  "amount": 120,
  "owner": "user_1"
},
{
  "_id": "2",
  "date": 1672119897,
  "amount": 25,
  "owner": "user_1"
},
{
  "_id": "3",
  "date": 1672119895,
  "amount": 40,
  "owner": "user_2"
},
{
  "_id": "4",
  "date": 1672119899,
  "amount": 70,
  "owner": "user_1"
},
{
  "_id": "5",
  "date": 1672119891,
  "amount": 33,
  "owner": "user_1"
},
{
  "_id": "6",
  "date": 1672119893,
  "amount": 11,
  "owner": "user_2"
}
```

And I'd like to create a view that returns the running total: ordered by ascending date, running total by owner.

Easy to do in SQL with window functions. But not sure how to achieve the same with CouchDB. I have no code to show.

Expected Output with running totals by owner, sorted by date descending:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "4",
    "date": 1672119899,
    "amount": 70,
    "owner": "user_1",
    "totalAmount": 248 // 178 + 70
  },
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "date": 1672119898,
    "amount": 120,
    "owner": "user_1",
    "totalAmount": 178 // 120 + 58
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "date": 1672119897,
    "amount": 25,
    "owner": "user_1",
    "totalAmount": 58 // 25 + 33
  },
  {
    "_id": "5",
    "date": 1672119891,
    "amount": 33,
    "owner": "user_1",
    "totalAmount": 33
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "date": 1672119895,
    "amount": 40,
    "owner": "user_2",
    "totalAmount": 51 // 40 + 51
  },
  {
    "_id": "6",
    "date": 1672119893,
    "amount": 11,
    "owner": "user_2",
    "totalAmount": 11
  }
]
```

Comment: In CouchDB, you can achieve this by using map reduce: in the map step, construct your key out of date + owner and emit the amount as value. Then, simply use _sum as reducer. See https://docs.couchdb.org/en/3.2.2-docs/ddocs/views/intro.html

Comment: That just calculates total transactions per owner per trip, not the running total though. The idea is that I need a list of transactions (or their IDs) with incrementing totals for EACH transaction.

Comment: Can you clarify what the expected output of the view is, including the JSON structure? It's not clear to me from your question.

Comment: @LyteFM updated the question per request. Let me know if this is helpful and thank you for looking into this issue.

Comment: CouchDB does not have OLAP functionality.  You will have to either create a middleware, handle the analysis client side, or go with something like [Couchbase](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/running-total-of-a-column/17680).